# Java JTextPane add emty space to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have A `JTextPane` inside a `JScrollPane`. What I am trying to achieve is to add an empty space under the `JTextPane` to allow the user to scroll further down the text pane, so that the last line (Which would be visible at the bottom of the frame) can be scrolled up to the first line position. Hard to explain so here have some pics:
[image]

My attempt to solve this was to add a `JPanel` with `Borderlayout.SOUTH` under the `JTextPane`. And update the `setPreferredSize(0, frameHeight - (const+ fontHeight))`

```
const = A constant value I got from experimenting

int fontHeight = textPane.getFontMetrics(textPane.getFont()).getHeight();
```

This works fine until you resize the font... Basically it is very hacky and doesn't seem to be very reliable.

**Question**: Is there a internal method to add this feature and if not how could I improve the existing solution for more stability?

**EDIT**-----------------
Here the working code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;


public class Main extends JFrame{
    private JTextPane zNum, tField;
    private JPanel scrollPanel;
    private JScrollPane tScrollPane;
    private Font font = new Font("Source Code Pro", Font.PLAIN, 12);

public Main(){
    super("Test Editor");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    zNum = new JTextPane();
    zNum.setText("1");
    zNum.setEditable(false);
    zNum.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 6, 2, 6));
    zNum.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    zNum.setFont(font);

    tField = new JTextPane();
    tField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 6, 2, 6));
    tField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tField.setFont(font);

    scrollPanel = new JPanel();
    scrollPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    scrollPanel.add(zNum, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    scrollPanel.add(tField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    scrollPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    tScrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel);
    tScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    getContentPane().add(tScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    // Resize
    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            updateMargin(tField);
        }
    });
}

void updateMargin(JTextPane textPane) {
    JViewport viewport = (JViewport)
        SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, textPane);

    if (viewport != null) {
        int len = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
        try {
            Rectangle end = textPane.modelToView(len);
            if (end != null) {
                tField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, viewport.getHeight() - (end.height + 4), 0));
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: `how could I improve the existing solution for more stability?` Well to improve something you need to post the code you want to improve. So... could you post it, please?

Comment: Well the code relevant to this feature are really just those two lines I posted in OP. I get the fontHeight and then I set the height of the Empty Space.

Comment: I mean by adding code, as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test it. Could you help us help you with it?

Comment: I was hoping for the easy way out :P If you can stand by I could try to write a snippet-version of my application,  but this could take a while..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the JTextPane's margin, based on the bounds of its enclosing JViewport and the last line of its document:

```
static void updateMargin(JTextPane textPane) {
    JViewport viewport = (JViewport)
        SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, textPane);

    if (viewport != null) {
        Insets margin = textPane.getMargin();

        int len = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
        try {
            Rectangle end = textPane.modelToView(len);
            if (end != null) {
                margin.bottom = viewport.getHeight() - end.height;
                textPane.setMargin(margin);
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll want to have that method called whenever the JTextPane is resized, when it becomes displayable, and when its text is changed.  For good measure, I would also call it if the JTextPane's inherited setPage method is called:

```
static void configureMargin(final JTextPane textPane) {
    textPane.addPropertyChangeListener("page", new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            updateMargin(textPane);
        }
    });

    textPane.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
        @Override
        public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent event) {
            long flags = event.getChangeFlags();
            if ((flags & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0) {
                updateMargin(textPane);
            }
        }
    });

    textPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            updateMargin(textPane);
        }
    });

    textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        private void updateTextPane() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateMargin(textPane);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            updateTextPane();
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            updateTextPane();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            updateTextPane();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. this is in deed smart. This way I don't have to fiddle around with fontHeights...  But I had to do a slight modification to your solution. I lied about the TextPane. There are in fact two JTextPanes inside a JPanel inside a JScrollPane. so at the end I apply the offset to the JPanel and not the JTextPane. And also since margin doesn't work on JPanels I used EmptyBorder. The result is this: it works but the last line is allowed to go out of the viewport by a few pixels. Is it because I use border?

Comment: I dont think the use of a Border would cause a problem.  I'm guessing you need to account for the existing margins of one or both of your JTextPanes.  If the JTextPanes are side by side, you might want to do the modelToView calls on each of them, and create a union of those two Rectangles.

Comment: The second JTextPane is for the Line Numbers (See pic in OP) so it should be fine with calculating only the main TextPane... But still it is off my few pixels, which results in offsets up to one line with extreme big/small font sizes. What Am I missing. PS I am writing a "TestBed", basically a mockup version of my application to post here so you can see what is going.

Comment: Good news is: Your code works. I tested it in my snippet app and it works like a charm. (Will update OP with the working code.) Bad news is that I now have to find the bug in my real application, which is going to be a pain in the )). If you wish you could have a peek in here https://github.com/Haeri/MonolithTextEditor and maybe find out what the problem is...??

Comment: PS: Since you are clearly a genius, may I ask a second question that buggs me for a long time: In the code you will see that the Line number TextPane is set BorderLayout.LINE_START. This makes it possible to scroll it out of the view in the x-axis.. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Never mind. Found it out. It was because I was always adding an extra line, so it was actually working, but the last line was always empty. But the x-scroll problem still remains...

Comment: Rather than placing both JTextPanes in a single panel, I would make the line number JTextPane the JScrollPane's [row header view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setRowHeaderView-java.awt.Component-).

Comment: I don't think it would.  A JScrollPane automatically synchronizes the vertical scrolling of the row header with the scrolling of the main viewport's content.

Comment: oh... I know whats wrong.. Its because the Line TextPane and the actual scrollpane have different heights because of that empty space we just inserted xD.. But how to fix this.

Comment: Since they are both JTextPanes, you can give them both the same margin.  Or put each of them in a JPanel with the same empty border.

Comment: I am now adding the border to both textpanes. this works now. But now a new problem appears.. the click area to focus on the text has been reduced.. Can I make an actionlistener on an emptyborder to react on clicks??

Comment: You can add a MouseListener to the JPanel which has the border, and in the listener's mouseClicked or mousePressed method, call textPane.requestFocusInWindow().  (But you wouldn't have to do that if you set the JTextPane's margin instead of using a JPanel and empty border.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65325/discussion-between-haeri-and-vgr).

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you could use a different Layout Manager. For example, with `GridBagLayout` you can set padding between components and between the border and the components. I cant confirm that this works though.

Comment: I am not sure how this would help.. The biggest issue with the current code is to calculate in every case the right height for the empty space.